# Android activity to handle multi threading

Tags: android, multithreading, button, asynchronous

In my activity class i want to perform a series of long calculations that require around 5 sec to complete when i press a button. So in order to do that i have create a new class which does all the calculations in its run method(since it implements Runnable) and when finished i set a variable to true to indicate that. In the code that checks the if the button is pressed i start a new Thread passing my class in it and then cheking whether the run method has finished or not. If it finished i then print the data. The problem with this is that when i check if the calculations have finished they actually havent so it pass that line of code and never prints the data. I have tried to do the Async Class method but still i think it wont work. Is there a way to create the thread when i press the button and keep checking if had finished so i can print the data? Which piece of code in an Activity is actually get executed over and over again? Thanks for any information.

```
if(v.equals(this.button)) {
             EditText param1 =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.param1);
             EditText param2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.param2);

            calculations = new MathCalc(param1.getText().toString(), param2.getText().toString());

            new Thread(calculations).start();

            while(!calculations.isReady());

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Show.class);
            intent.putExtra("show1", calculations.getResult());
            startActivity(intent);

            }
```

This is want i want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AsyncTask is the right tool for this. The typical use case for the AsyncTask is that you want to do something small in the background and leave feedback through the UI before, during and/or after the task is done.

Be aware that running things in the background can get you in trouble if the user quits and restarts your activity a lot, since the background task will not end when the Activity is removed from screen.

An example activity is shown below. You could add the `onPreExecute` and `onProgress` methods to the AsynchTask to give the user feedback before and during the calculation.

```
    public class CalcActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView resultView;

    public void onCreate() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                AsyncCalculation calc = new AsyncCalculation();
                calc.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public class AsyncCalculation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int result = 0;
            // Do some calculation
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Set the result, start another activity or do something else
            resultView.setText("The result was " + result);
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this won't work with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You basically need to override two methods - `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`. 
You're guaranteed that `onPostExecute()` will be invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. You also don't have to worry how to update the UI Thread from another thread.

Here's a good [example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask).

Comment: So if i create the class in the AsyncTask class and call the calculations in doBackroung(), all of this when i press the button, what shall i return in postexecute? Because it wont return anything. I might actually switch the Activity there? If i wanted to pass some data to the main Activity i should have pass the class itelf in the AsyncTask and access/edit those data?

Comment: Read carefully the documentation. Whatever you return in doInBackground() is automatically passed as parameter to onPostExecute().

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favouriteButton);
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                        public void run() {

                            while(!isDone){
                               doAlotOfCalculations();
                            }
                        }
                });
                thread.start();
              } 
});




private void doAlotOfCalculations(){
    ...    
    if(whenDone){
        isDone = true;
    }
    ....
}
```

> Which piece of code in an Activity is actually get executed over and
>   over again?

There is no such a thing.
It is just onResume which executes every time you start(restart) this activity

Comment: Thanks for responding. This might work, but things get more complicate as when the calculations are finished i might want to switch Activity and passing some values.

Comment: @Stelios Do you want to do your calculations in another activity or some class? do you want to pass results from one activity to another? then you should use Intent or SharedPreferences

Comment: Yes exactly, i am doing the calculations in another class when i press a button and then i need to now when they are finished and access them via getter. I am using an intent and i have passed the values and evrything work but i have accomplished this by starting the thread(the class itself) and have a while loop to check wether it has finished. This makes hte application not responding but after 3-4 secs it changes activity and the data is there. I just want to do this in background so that it wont freeze.

Comment: I have work with java GUIs before and i had a thread running and cheking for this thread to finish so i accomplished that in java.

Comment: i think that then you should use something like: isDone = CalcutationClass.doAlotOfCalculations(); and put this expression in the thread, the one i described in the answer.. you don't have to wait for the class to finish its calculations. Otherwise AsyncTask is also a good idea

Comment: or just show some pieces of your code, so it would be more obvious what kind of problem you have